# CSS: How can I break a timestamp – or any other sentence – at the colon

Tags: html, css

I think I got all combinations of **word-break** and **overflow-wrap** in this jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/thcurgsw/1/

I have timestamps in the format `YYYYMMDD:HHMMSS` and want the CSS to break them at the colon. But neither in FireFox nor in Chrome do they break as one would expect them to do: they break in the middle of the number, but not at the colon. Do I miss another CSS-setting here or is this a browser bug?

PS: I also tried combinations of **line-break** to no avail.

The expected behaviour is whitespace > interpunctuation > hyphens > anything else

Comment: A slightly messy way would be to replace the colon with :<span style="color: transparent">&shy;</span> i.e. use a soft hyphen.

Comment: Yeah, but … shouldnt interpunctation be a default place for breaks before breaking in the middle of a number or some word?

Comment: This is not how the CSS property is supposed to work, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break), you cannot specify a character. I guess it would break if your div has the exact width like the first part (YYYYMMDD) - there are some tricks/workarounds at the end of this [css-tricks.com article](https://css-tricks.com/where-lines-break-is-complicated-heres-all-the-related-css-and-html/).

Comment: @Christian you can specify a soft hyphen though.

Comment: @Christian I dont want to specify a char, i'd just expect it to behave like any sane linebreak: whitespace > interpunctuation > hyphens > anything else.

Comment: Can you edit the source code HTML of this text? for example breaking the `YYYYMMDD:HHMMSS` into `<span>YYYYMMDD:</span><span>HHMMSS</span>` ?

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and the expected result

Comment: @NicoHaase "I have timestamps in the format YYYYMMDD:HHMMSS and want the CSS to break them at the colon. "

Comment: Please add **all** clarification to your question, including the markup you are currently using

Answer (score -1):

```css
div {
  width:7em;
  background: #f88;
  margin: 0.2em;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="wn on"><span>20230416:</span>204704</div>
```

Comment: This is not a css solution.

Comment: Your problem cannot be solved with `word-break` and `overflow-wrap` alone. I have provided you the easiest solution.

Answer (score -1):

You should only add `width: fit-content;` attribute to `div`. And take the code in to the `<div>` which section you want to wrap second line.  You can check it from below snippet.

```css
div {
  width:7em;
  background: #f88;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="wn on">20230416:<div>204704</div></div>
<br>
<div class="wa on">20230416:<div>204704</div></div>
<br>
<div class="wk on">20230416:<div>204704</div></div>
<br>
<div class="ww on">20230416:<div>204704</div></div>
<br>
<div class="wn ow">20230416:<div>204704</div></div>
<br>
<div class="wa ow">20230416:<div>204704</div></div>
<br>
<div class="wk ow">20230416:<div>204704</div></div>
<br>
<div class="ww ow">20230416:<div>204704</div></div>
<br>
<div class="wn oa">20230416:<div>204704</div></div>
<br>
<div class="wa oa">20230416:<div>204704</div></div>
<br>
<div class="wk oa">20230416:<div>204704</div></div>
<br>
<div class="ww oa">20230416:<div>204704</div></div>
```

Comment: This changes the width, not the wrapping.